# Не выполняется подготовленный запрос в бд php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;    
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (
user_id, user_status, user_email, user_pass, user_name, user_surname, user_avatar)
VALUES (NULL, '2', ?, ?, ?, ?, '/front/img/users/user.png');");
$stmt->bind_param($this->email, $this->pass, $this->name, $this->surname);

/* выполнение подготовленного выражения  */
if (!$stmt->execute()) {echo "ошибочка!";};

/* Закрытие соединения и выражения*/
$stmt->close();
```

код выше выдает ошибку..

P.S. Все переменные проверял на наличие значений, они все не пустые.
Отредактировал код, теперь даже не доходит до вывода ошибки

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (
user_id, user_status, user_email, user_pass, user_name, user_surname, user_avatar)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param('NULL', '2', $this->email, $this->pass, $this->name, $this->surname, '/front/img/users/user.png');
```

Comment: Какую именно ошибку выдаёт код?

Comment: Еще два замечания к приведенному коду. 1. строка 'NULL' не имеет ничего общего с пустым значением NULL. 2. Значения нельзя вписывать напрямую в bind_param, а можно только передавать в виде переменных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::bind_param` первым параметром принимает строку, которая описывает типы параметров, а далее идут сами параметры. Всего есть 4 разных идентификатора

- **i** - integer (целое число)
- **d** - double (число с плавающей точкой)
- **s** - string (строка)
- **b** - BLOB

Например, для четырех строковых параметров вызов должен быть таким

```
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $this->email, $this->pass, $this->name, $this->surname);
```

Ну и далее, вместо

> `if (!$stmt->execute()) {echo "ошибочка!";};`

Пишите так

```
if (!$stmt->execute())
  echo $stmt->error;
```

Будет больше пищи для размышлений

Comment: ошибка "No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"

Comment: @Nikolay Вы указали первым параметром `bind_param` нужные типы параметров?

Comment: там должны быть строки.. получены таким способом: 
   `$name = $_POST["name"];`

Comment: @Nikolay Отредактировал ответ

Comment: добавил инфу в вопрос

Comment: И я могу ошибаться, но я изначально разве не по тому шаблону писал, который был предложен в ответе?

Comment: @Nikolay в ответе первым параметром идет значение `ssss` что обозначает четыре строковых значения. Отредактировал ответ еще раз

Comment: очень благодарю!)